# microsoft office interop word: how to know if a paragraph is a caption

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I'm writing a VSTO add-ins in C# that parses an Office Word document.

I have to check if each figure of the document has a caption label.
I managed to know when a paragraph contains a Figure:

```
var activeDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;


for (int i = 0; i < activeDoc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    Paragraph par = activeDoc.Paragraphs[i + 1];

    if (par.Range.InlineShapes.Count == 1)
    {
        // the paragraph has an image
    }
}
```

but I don't see any ways to know if the paragraph is a caption or simple text.

I tried to use [CaptionLabels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.captionlabels?view=word-pia) but it returns the types of the captions [Figure, Table, Equation] and not all the captions in my documents.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation is not always clear and the same applies to CaptionLabel but my guess is that the CaptionLabel.parent property is the InlineShape object.  So just compare the CaptionLabels against the InlineShapes using the parent property. Then use the position property to match against the preceding or the following paragraph (inlineShape.range.Paragraphs (1).next or .previous)

Comment: From my investigation CaptionLabel is not the correct object. It seems that the "caption" information is attached to the Paragraph object, in the OpenXML format it's in the ParagraphProperties but I didn't find any corrispondence in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library.

Comment: Your're right. I ran a quick test and the paragraph that is a caption has a builtin style applied that's called 'Caption' (par.Style.NameLocal)

If that name is always 'Caption' (or you feed it as a parameter) then you can distinguish non-caption paragraphs from captions.

Comment: par.Style.NameLocal !!! finally found it, thanks! You can write the answer so I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick test and the paragraph that is a caption has a builtin style applied that's called 'Caption' (par.Style.NameLocal) If that name is always 'Caption' (or you feed it as a parameter) then you can distinguish non-caption paragraphs from captions.

As a tip: write a little test code and put a breakpoint to examine the objects and find what makes them unique. In this case the paragraph/range style is 'Caption'. This is the most efficient way imo.

Comment: I discovered that NameLocal depends on the language hence my code doesn't work with a different language set in Office Word. It's a solution but not the optimal one.

Comment: you then use wdBuiltInStyle.wdStyleCaption to compare the par.Style to the builtIn style Caption (I should have mentioned this in the answer, will do once you confirm it works)

Comment: WdBuiltInStyle (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle?view=word-pia) is not comparable with the Style type.

Comment: you've got to compare the names: if par.Range.Style.NameLocal = Doc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleCaption).NameLocal then ...

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to use that WdXYZ enums.